# how to do django SMTP setting using aws instance with EIP and default domain name

Tags: django, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

Have took 2 day, can't find a good method.

1.AWS Linux instance have pre-install sendmail, I only need to send out email. But don't how to configure sendmail and other package.

2.Try to use AWS SES, however it needs to verify domain, which means I need to deal with AWS Router 53. After reading very complicated document and "create hosted zone", the AWS SES domain verification still "pending" after 24 hours. I am guessing maybe the default EIP domain name, like "ec2-***-amazonaws.com" is not a qualified/Registered domainn ?

As a newbie for SMTP setting, really don't know what to do? Since even if using a free mail server, it seems still need to 'verify domain', if aws default domain name "ec2-***-amazonaws.com" is invalid, how can I pass the domain verification?

By the way, since sendmail is pre-install, and this website is very simple, small group used, how to set configuration and other package to do email server on this instance itself?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier if you configure email from your Django app directly to a third party email provider, effectively by-passing the local sendmail configuration altogether. Trying to set up an email connection to AWS/SES on the server itself is also a pain, it's also much easier to configure the Django app to connect directly to AWS/SES

You have three very popular choices to setup email from Django:

- Set up a connection to Gmail/Google apps .- If you'll be sending a lot of email volume I wouldn't recommend this option, because they block you easily if you use it to relay a lot of email.
- Set up a connection to AWS/SES.- You mention you already tried this, but now try to set the connection inside Django using the Python packages `boto` and `django-ses`, this will make the email setup much easier. In addition, `boto` is also useful if you plan to use some other AWS service like S3.
- Set up a connection to Mandrill.- This is another provider, not as big as Google or AWS, but they provide good service with decent free email volume and you can also set up a connection directly from Django.

Take a look at this article -- which I wrote -- that describes all the set up steps for all three providers in detail: 
http://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangoemail.html

Comment: Thank you very much for such good explanation. I have read your article, and success for the 1st choice : through Gmail.  I will try the 2nd choice: AWS/SES, just want to confirm: do I need to verify domain in SES first? or I don't need to do anything in AWS/SES, just pip install django-ses with settings "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" and "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" ?

Comment: To my knowledge you don't need to verify the domain to use SES in this way. The AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are sufficient to authenticate yourself. In addtion to pip install django-ses, you also need boto, so also do pip install boto

Comment: I tried AWS/SES with settings "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" and "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", also verified an email address. However there was always an error: <Type> Sender ,<Code>MessageRejected</Code>, <Message>Email address is not verified.</Message>.   BTW, settings.py with EMAIL_FROM, SERVER_EMAIL, EMAIL_HOST_USER, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, all = <the verified email in SES>.

Comment: You definitely have to verify the domain in SES if you want to send emails to anything other than a test email address.

Comment: For AWS/SES did you you change the back-end to EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend' ? It sounds like it's still trying to connect to the local sendmail first to send it to AWS/SES. Also make sure you comment out all the other email variables in settings.py (like EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_HOST_USER which may be overriding the django-ses settings)